# Executing different batch inserting into one transaction in Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb

I need to execute two different inserts for two different collections, one depends on the other one, so I need to execute the first one and then being able to execute the second one. My problem is I need to be able to roll back all operations if some error happens so I need to roll back both inserts if an error occurs.

I'm trying to do something like this with my two batch calls inside of the transactions but it doesn't work.

```
conn.beginTransaction()
  .then(() => {
    conn.query("INSERT INTO testTransaction values ('test')");
    return conn.query("INSERT INTO testTransaction values ('test2')");
    //instead of this two query I have my batch inserts
  })
  .then(() => {
    conn.commit();
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    conn.rollback();
  })
```

Any example of how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just if someone has the same situation and what to know how I figure this out, here is a working code:

```
return connectionMaria.beginTransaction()
      .then(() => {
              return conn.batch(insert1, values1)
                 .then(() => {
                    return conn.batch(insert2, values2) 
                  })
      .then(() => {
                     connectionMaria.commit();
                  })
      .catch((error) => {
                           connectionMaria.rollback();
                           throw error;
                         });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of promises you need to wait on, you can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
conn.beginTransaction()
  .then(() => {
    return Promise.all([
      conn.query("INSERT INTO testTransaction values ('test')"),
      conn.query("INSERT INTO testTransaction values ('test2')")
    ])
  })
  .then(() => {
    conn.commit();
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    conn.rollback();
  })
```

Comment: I need to wait until insert1 being done in order to execute insert2, that's why Promise.All() approaches didn't work for me. But thanks